# How to correctly deal with optional spaces on ReadP?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, haskell

When using `ReadP` to parse a grammar, I notice the parser often gets exponential. Most of the times, I end up identifying the issue is triggered by some bad usage of `skipSpaces`, although I'm not sure when exactly that happens. What is the right way to deal with optional spaces when parsing with ReadP?

Comment: Instead of adding an `edit` note you should *actually* perform an edit and remove unnecessary details that aren't relevant. There's the edit history if we want to see what, how and when something changed in a post.

Comment: @Bakuriu I am sorry, I updated the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most prevalent technique I've seen to deal with spaces is to have each token consume the white space immediately following it.

A convenience combinator like the following can help out with this:

```
tok p = p <* spaces
```

For example, this combinator definition:

```
adt d = Adt <$> between (string "#(") (char ')') (sepBySpaced ctor (char '|')) = ...
```

would be written as:

```
adt d = Adt <$> between (tok $ string "#(") (tok $ char ')') (sepBySpaced ctor (tok $ char '|')) = ...
```

The only caveat is that you have to make sure you remove/skip over any white space at the start of your input.